# Why do I have to write some statements inside of these signs < ... >_?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Basic.
(Sorry, if my english isn't that good. I'm not a native speaker.)

Why do I have to write **System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()** inside of these signs **< ... >_** ?

And what does the underscore at the end of the line do?

You can see it in the first line of the code below.

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.txtZahl1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.txtZahl2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
```

Comment: The `<foo>` things are called attributes, you dont have to add `DebuggerStepThrough` to that one - the code inside is maintained by VS, so you dont need to worry about it.  The "_" is the line continuation character.  In VS 2010+ you dont need it either.  Not entirely sure if that is what you are asking...

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot for your quick answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

It signifies an [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

They allow you to associate declarative info with the class or function  you're creating, which could be used in reflection for example.

In the case of the attribute you're using, it "Instructs the debugger to step through the code instead of stepping into the code.", per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!